# how to align a set of button to bottom of the screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout there are four sections respectively a header, an editable control, a list and a set of button.  I want to keep the buttons bottom of the screen.  I make too many changes in the layout to force the buttons to bottom.  But nothing happened.  Please provide instructions to make what i needed.  I am posting the layout also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--  heading for basic settings -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroheading"
            style="@style/txtHeading" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

         <!--  macro name -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"                    
                android:text="Macro Name"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_macroname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:singleLine="true"/>                 
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMacroList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

        <!-- Save & Cancel button -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
                android:text="Save"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onCancelButtonClick"
                android:text="Cancel"/>         
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the Parent of the LinearLayout containing the button as relative and set the property of linear layout containing two buttons as android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". You can also set the gravity of the Linear Layout to Bottom.

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--  heading for basic settings -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroheading"
        style="@style/txtHeading" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

     <!--  macro name -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"                    
            android:text="Macro Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:singleLine="true"/>                 
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMacroList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
    <!-- Save & Cancel button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
            android:text="Save"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onCancelButtonClick"
            android:text="Cancel"/>         
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Take the main parent as Relative layout and give `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the layout of the buttons...

Comment: Is it possible without changing the layout to relative ?

Comment: try moving the button layout outside of scroll view but still you need to take one main realtive layout which will hold both scroll view and bottom button layout

Comment: I changed mainlayout to relative and removed scrollview , now all controls overlapping each other

Comment: see this is because previously you were using Linear layout and views were automatically aliigned below because of Vertical orientation but now you have used Relative layout so now you have to aliggn them below each other yourself using layout_below property

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the parent layout as relative and then use the property android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to sublayout.

Answer (score 2):

Relative layout is the best way to do it as Karan_Rana suggested, but if you dont want to use relative layout try this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--  heading for basic settings -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

     <!--  macro name -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"                    
            android:text="Macro Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:singleLine="true"/>                 
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMacroList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 <!-- Save & Cancel button -->
         <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
            android:text="Save"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onCancelButtonClick"
            android:text="Cancel"/>         
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here, you need to use LinearLayout as parent and set `weightSum` to it and apply the same `layout_weight` to the layout you want in fullscreen. And the layout which you want in bottom(save and cancel) apply `layout_weight` to 0.

This works well!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code by making relative layout as parent layout and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your button layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<!-- heading for basic settings -->

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <!-- macro name -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Macro Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_macroname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Save & Cancel button -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onCancelButtonClick"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Modify" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Cancle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

for display button at bottom.