# Issues in Android relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Following my previous question [how to align a set of button to bottom of the screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446201/how-to-align-a-set-of-button-to-bottom-of-the-screen-in-android), i correct with the help of [user1566160](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566160/user1566160).  After that i fall on another problem.  I will explain with the help of two images.

[image: ok shows nice display]

when i press on edittext to change macro name, the position of save & cancel buttons changes

[image]

my layout as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <!--  heading for basic settings -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <!--  macro name -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"                    
            android:text="Macro Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"/>                 
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMacroList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


<!-- Save & Cancel button -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onSaveButtonClick"
        android:text="Save"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onCancelButtonClick"
        android:text="Cancel"/>         
   </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

how can i resolve it ?

Comment: use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" which will avoid the bottom buttons to be pushed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest in your activity tag